# Trigger jQuery 1.5 ajax request manually

Tags: jquery

I want to set up all the callbacks and other settings, using something like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
.success(function() { alert("success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

But i don't want it to automatically start the AJAX request, because I want to trigger it later, by myself.

If it is possible, then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your code in function and call it whenever you want.

Comment: I decided for that method as a "temporary" fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
var ajaxSetup = {
  url: "example.php",
  success: function() {
  },
  ...
}
...
```

then when you want to call it:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(ajaxSetup);
```